# Is it possible to use EJS without routes with nodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ejs

I'm running a NodeJS script that will generate several PDF reports.

Thing is I need to generate several graph for each PDFs, so after several problems, I decided to generate graphs in PNG format, then, make the html page including images. From the HTML, I generate a PDF.

Thing is I don't really need routes, but I need EJS, and I need req / res to generate my graphs:

```
app.get("/operations/:operation/meters/:meter/weekly_report", async (req, res) => { // Used to generate PNG from graph
    const meterId = req.params.meter;
    const week = req.query.week;
    // get meters from meter
    const meter = meters.find(it => it.prm === meterId);
    const weeklyData = await generateWeeklyGraphForPRM(meter, week);
    ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/partials/', "weekly_graph.ejs"), {
        days: weeklyData.days,
        conso: weeklyData.consoByHour,
        meterLabel: meter.label,

    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {

            res.render('partials/weekly_graph.ejs', {
                days: weeklyData.days,
                conso: weeklyData.consoByHour,
                meterLabel: meter.label,
            });
        }
    });
```

And Then:

```
async function makePngScreenshot(url, meterId, filename) {
    axios.get(url, null); // Make the request to generate html page
    const destination = "public/images/" + operation.data.name + "/" + DATE_INI + "_" + DATE_END + "/" + meterId
    return new Pageres({delay: 2, filename: filename})
        .src(url, ['1300x650'], {crop: true})
        .dest(destination)
        .run()

}
    });
```

Thing is working, but right now, everything is in index.js

I am trying to break the code into several files.

As I extract each routes into a routes.js, I have the problem that I can't share any longer global vars with all my endpoints.

So, here I find 3 solutions:

- Use functions instead of endpoints: I don't need endpoints, but I don't know how to render an EJS file without routes, req / res.
- In each routes, get each object again ( inefficient )
- Use a redis, or any cache ( ok, but I would like to avoid any extra component for now )

The easiest one should be converting routes into functions, but how can I generate EJS files, without routes, is it possible ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand what it means you do not need a route? Do you want to make a script to which you pass the input data, it performs the task and stops its work?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need no API, as this would be a job to trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your task correctly. I made an example of a program that starts using the command line, receives the command line arguments `meterId` and `week`, generates a `.html` file from the `.ejs` template. I also used the `yargs` package to easily parse command line arguments.

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const ejs = require('ejs');

const fsp = fs.promises;

// It would be a good idea to store these parameters in an .env file
const INPUT_FILENAME = 'test.ejs';
const OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'result.html';
const TEMPLATE_FILE = path.resolve(__dirname, './templates', INPUT_FILENAME);
const STORAGE_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './storage', OUTPUT_FILENAME);

(async function main({ meterId, week }) {
    if (!meterId) {
        return console.warn('Specify the command line parameter "meterId"!');
    }
    
    if (!week) {
        return console.warn('Specify the command line parameter "week"!');
    }

    try {
        const html = await ejs.renderFile(TEMPLATE_FILE, { meterId, week }, { async: true });
        await fsp.writeFile(STORAGE_PATH, html);
        console.log('Done.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})(argv);
```

And an example command to run the script:

```
node script.js --meterId=141 --week=44
```

Please let me know if I understood your task correctly and if my example helps somehow.